# App script OK_CANCEL Buttons

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The Google Apps Script's inputBox works. For example something simple like:

```
var myUserString = Browser.inputBox('Title', 'Write something', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
```

However, pressing the <kbd>enter</kbd> key has no effect whatsoever. You have to go to your mouse and press e.g. `OK` to proceed. Why doesn't <kbd>enter</kbd> just equal `OK`?

Will this be fixed or is it possible to fix it with some additional code?

Comment: I kept searching the docs but didn't find anything. Probably your best shot is using [macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros) and see if you can bind a prompt closure to `enter`

Comment: thanks! i will try it @Adelin

Comment: Does using the more modern `UI#prompt` have the same behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's the behaviour enforced by Google and we can't change them, easily.

If you're adamant on using `enter` as submit, then you can build a custom sidebar with javascript code to support `enter` as submit.

Reference and further reads : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object)

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: This should get you started https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showSidebar(Object)